Strype Fund Transfer to Bank Account Laravel
I aim to transfer my Strype funds to someone else's bank account.I am trying the following approach.
    // generate test bank account token
    public function generateBankAccountToken()
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('stripe.sk'));
        try {
            $token = Token::create([
                'bank_account' => [
                    'country' => 'US',
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'account_holder_name' => 'Test User',
                    'account_holder_type' => 'individual',
                    'routing_number' => '110000000', // Test routing number
                    'account_number' => '000999999991', // Test account number
                ],
            ]);
            return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }


 // to redirect amount from stripe to bank account
    public function initiateTransfer(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->validate([
            'account' => ['required'],
            'amount' => ['required', new CheckBalance],
        ]);

        // set the stripe API token
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('stripe.sk'));
        try {
            // Create a transfer to the recipient's bank account
            $transfer = Transfer::create([
                'amount' =>  100,
                'currency' => 'usd',  // Currency code
                'destination' => 'abtok_1PVXsvAzd6Qck0TGa8chJlfd',  // Replace with recipient's Stripe account ID
                'description' => 'Refund from balance',  // Optional description
            ]);

            // Redirect the user to the Stripe transfer page
            return redirect()->away($transfer->destination_payment_url);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Handle transfer failure
            dd($e);
            return back()->withError('Transfer could not be initiated: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }


In the route file:
    Route::put('/recharge/initiate-Transfer', 'initiateTransfer')->name('strype.initiate.transfer');
    Route::get('test/bank-account', 'generateBankAccountToken')->name('strype.test.bank');

After calling the strype.test.bank route I am getting the token: btok_1PVXsvAzd6Qck0TGa8chJlfd.
However, after applying the token on the initiateTransfer function, I am getting the following error.
Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException {#1605 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\PaymentController\StripeController.php:156
  #message: "No such destination: 'acct_1MQccXIQ2pUmxoSJ'"
  #code: 0
  .........................................


You're confusing two concepts: Transfers and Payouts. Are you a platform that wants to payout their merchant or are you looking to get paid out what the customers purchase from you?
